# Insert or Update in an DBLINK as a Loop

Tags: loops, plsql, collections, dblink

I have a Row, which i wannt to Insert (or Update if the ID is already used) from another Schema with an DBLINK. This Table has many FKs, so i need to Update or Insert(if doesnt exist) around 20 Tables.

I tried it by writting all needed Rows from the different Tables from the DBLINK into Variables and then checked if the Targeted Tables had this rows already. Im sure that there is a much easier way to do it. A loop where the tables and their rowtypes are saved in an Collection with execute immdediate for example, but i couldnt find anything.

This example is like 20 times in my Code and im sure that there is an easier way to do it then writting this over and over.

```
PROCEDURE Test_copy (pi_id IN NUMBER) IS

V_REC_Table1   Table1%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table2   Table2%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table3   Table3%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table4   Table4%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table5   Table5%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table6   Table6%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table7   Table7%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table8   Table8%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table9   Table9%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table10  Table10%ROWTYPE;


V_REC_Table1_exists   Table1%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table2_exists   Table2%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table3_exists   Table3%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table4_exists   Table4%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table5_exists   Table5%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table6_exists   Table6%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table7_exists   Table7%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table8_exists   Table8%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table9_exists   Table9%ROWTYPE;
V_REC_Table10_exists  Table10%ROWTYPE;
v_sql VARCHAR2(2000);

Begin
    v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM Table1@dblink WHERE ID = '||pi_id;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO V_REC_DBLINK_Table1;
Exception
    when no_data_found then
    Raise_application_Error(-20001, 'ID doesnt exist');
END;

Begin
    v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM Table2@dblink WHERE ID = '||V_REC_Table1.T2_ID;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO V_REC_DBLINK_Table2;
Exception
    when no_data_found then
    Raise_application_Error(-20001, 'ID doesnt exist');
END;
(and so on)
.
.
.
BEGIN
        v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = '||V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.ID;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1_EXISTS;
        
    UPDATE TABLE1
        SET ID          = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.ID,
            NAME        = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.NAME,
            DESCRIPTION = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.DESCRIPTION
            NOTE        = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.NOTE
            NUMBER      = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.NUMBER
            ADDRESS     = V_REC_DBLINK_Table1.ADDRESS
        WHERE ID = V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.ID;
        
    EXCEPTION
        when no_data_found then
            INSERT INTO TABLE1
            (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, NOTE, NUMBER, ADDRESS)
            Values(V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.ID
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.NAME
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.DESCRIPTION
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.NOTE
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.NUMBER
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE1.ADDRESS);
    END;

BEGIN
        v_sql := 'SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID = '||V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2.ID;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2_EXISTS;
        
    UPDATE TABLE2
        SET ID          = V_REC_DBLINK_Table2.ID,
            NAME        = V_REC_DBLINK_Table2.NAME,
            DESCRIPTION = V_REC_DBLINK_Table2.DESCRIPTION
        WHERE ID = V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2.ID;
        
    EXCEPTION
        when no_data_found then
            INSERT INTO TABLE2
            (ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION)
            Values(V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2.ID
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2.NAME
                  ,V_REC_DBLINK_TABLE2.DESCRIPTION);
    END;
    (and so on for all Tables via DBLINK)
```

Any suggestions? I just want to do that in a shorter way(maybe via Collection and loop).

Comment: Check out the MERGE statement. That does exactly what you need in a single sql statement.

Comment: There are triggers which prevent me from using MERGE and Im not allowed to disable them for a second. MERGE only does the query showed above easier but doesnt help me with my main problem to make the Tables i use changeable, so that i can write a loop where i only change the name of the Table (and rowtype) to cast it as EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Can you give some more info ? It's not so clear what you are atrying to achieve. You're asking about storing table names and rowtypes but there is not rowtype reference in your code.

Comment: Please provide complete table definitions. especially the target tables where you need to change the rowtype? Is it just the column order but same names? Additionally provide sample data, as text - **no images** that covers each condition, and the expected results of that data. Note: There is no trigger which prevents use of MERGE. It will fire any Insert or Update (or even Delete) triggers as needed. Finally, the current UPDATE will not change any data; the structure *Update table2 set id = table2.id* is exactly the same as *Update table2 set id = id* and the same for the other columns.